# Check if Python list contains a specific element

Tags: python, list

I wrote a sample program to generate a hash code from input (it's not done yet so you don't see the part where it actually generates the hash):

```
import hashlib

def isInputValid(input, validInput=[]):
    for i in validInput:
        if validInput[i] == input: # error generated here
            return True
            pass
        i = i + 1
    return False
    pass

sha1hash = hashlib.sha1()
choiceValidInputs = ["1", "2"]

print ("Welcome to hash generator!\n")
print ("[1] -- generate hash from input")
print ("[2] -- quit")
choice = input("\nWhat do you want to do? ")
if not isInputValid(choice, choiceValidInputs):
    print ("Invalid option; try again")
    choice = input("What do you want to do? ")

if choice == "1":
    print ("\n[1] SHA1/SHA256")
    print ("[2] SHA512")
    hashType = input("\nWhat hash type do you want? ")
    ...
elif choice == "2":
    print ("Goodbye!")
    quit()
```

My Terminal window:

```
kali@kali:~$ python3 /home/bin/hashgenerator.py 
Welcome to hash generator!

[1] -- generate hash from input
[2] -- quit

What do you want to do? 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bin/hashgenerator.py", line 19, in <module>
    if isInputValid(choice, choiceInput)==False:
  File "/home/bin/hashgenerator.py", line 5, in isInputValid
    if validInput[i] == input:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
kali@kali:~$
```

I want to check if the input is present in `choiceValidInputs`. I actually don't really know how to work with lists etc. in Python.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Your choice valid inputs are all strings, lists indices must be integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looping through elements not indexes

If you want to use indexes:

```
def isInputValid(input, validInput=[]):
    for i in range(len(validInput)):
        if validInput[i] == input: # error generated here
            return True
```

If you want to use elements you can do

```
def isInputValid(input, validInput=[]):
    for i in validInput:
        if i == input: # error generated here
            return True
```

But you can do it more easily. And more correctly :)

```
def isInputValid(input, validInput=[]):
    return input in validInput
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in validInput:
    if validInput[i] == input:
```

`i` here is not an index of an item in `validInput`, it is the item itself. What you want to do is:

```
for i in validInput:
    if i == input:
```

Besides, you don't need `pass` and `i = i+1` below. And I would suggest renaming variable `input` to something else to avoid confusion with `input()` function.