# List the elements containing the value in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the list which contains a specific value.

```
fullint = []
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
for k in students:
    fullint.append(k[1])

 fullint.sort()
 valuetobefound = fullint[1]
```

Here the valuetobefound variable contains the value 37.21. All I want is to print the list `['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21]` which contains the value 37.21 inside students list. I have tried

```
for valuetobefound in students:
    print(valuetobefound)
```

But this output returns all the lists `['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]` instead of `['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21]`. All I need is the list containing the value 37.21. Can anyone please guide me or tell me the logic to achieve this?.. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if Python list contains a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148757/check-if-python-list-contains-a-specific-element)

Comment: I'd advise using a `map` and not a `nested list` here.

Comment: Where does `valuetobefound` come from? If you set it to `37.21` before the loop, it gets gazumped by the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this result, filtering out every tuple that doesn't match your needs.

```py
>>> students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
>>> my_val = 37.21
>>> students_match = [(stud, val) for (stud, val) in students if val == my_val]
>>> students_match
[('Harry', 37.21), ('Berry', 37.21)]
```

Comment: Or `[[stud, val] for (stud, val) in ...]` to keep the result as a list of lists. Although a tuple is more appropriate, the OP may not want that. +1 for the only answer using a list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, I though about using lists, but tuple probably is the most appropriate data structure here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]

some_list = []
for k in students:
    if k[1] == 37.21:
        some_list.append(k)
        
print(some_list) #[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21]]
```

After that `some_list` should contain what you want.